# Match a specific number of characters in string and delete python

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains a number of lines.  Some lines begin with a specific number of characters.  I want to find the set of characters that contain that number and delete them and the space after.  Here is an example of the list.

```
MARVEL COMICS

JUN130675   AGE OF ULTRON HC    $75.00
JUL130663   ALL NEW X-MEN #16   $3.99
JUL130606   AVENGERS AI #3  $2.99
JUL130642   DAREDEVIL DARK NIGHTS #4
```

I want to find that set of 9 characters at the start of the string and delete them plus the white space.  There are always 9 and always at the start.  This text file contains many lines so I want to step through each line and save the output in a new text file.  The name of starting file is final.txt.  My language of choice is python.

Thanks

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the rule that tells you that "JUN130675" is something to skip, but "MARVEL CO" is not? If you can describe the rule in English, you can describe it in code.

For example, maybe the rule is just that "JUN130675" is nothing but letters and numbers, while "MARVEL CO" has something else in the middle (a space). Let's write that in Python:

```
def fix_line(line):
    if line[:9].isalnum():
        return line[10:].lstrip()
    else:
        return line
```

That `line[:9]` gets the first 9 characters, [`isalnum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) checks that all characters are letters or numbers. If so, `line[10:]` skips the first 9 characters, and [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) skips the space after them.

Then we just apply that to each line:

```
with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(fixline(line))
```

Or, if the rule is that it has to be letters and numbers, and only capital letters, and must be followed by a space… that's just three conditions joined by `and` in Python, just as in English, so write it that way:

```
def fix_line(line):
    if line[:9].isalnum() and line[:9] == line[:9].upper() and line[9:10].isspace():
        # everything else is the same
```

Comment: I really like your explanation but what if instead of  MARVEL COMICS we had FOOBARFOO COMICS? We still have 9 alnum characters followed by whitespace, applying upper changes nothing so we will remove them.

Comment: Yes, this could be a problem.  I should have posted more of the list but there are comics from all publishers.  DC Comics etc....  I was hoping to key off of the 9 set of characters.  I do like your clean solution.

Comment: @zero323: That's exactly why you have to know what rule you want. The first rule will treat "FOOBARFOO COMICS" as a line to edit; the second rule (because of the "must be followed by a space" bit) will not. Or waht if we had just "FOOBARFOO" with nothing else? Maybe the rule is "3 capital letters, then 6 digits, then at least one space"? Or "one of the 12 month abbreviations, then 6 digits, then at least one space"? The only person who knows is the person whose data this is.

Comment: I just want to delete the 9 characters and leave everything else.

Comment: @user138389: But what does "key off the 9 set of characters" mean? You need to turn that into a rule which any idiot can apply and decide whether a line matches or not. I've suggested a number of possible rules, but I had no idea which one you actually want.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to be more clear.  I want to find and delete that pattern of 9 characters.  It is always capitalized, always starts with 3 letters followed by 6 numbers and it is always at the start of the line.  Everything else needs to remain, name of comic the price and the publisher.  I think your solution posted last will work.  Let me try thank you

Comment: @user138389: Do you not know how to translate that rule to Python, following the examples I gave in my answer? `line[:3].isupper() and line[3:9].isdigit()` should do it. (Also, note that this rule would treat "FOO987654321 COMICS" as matching the pattern. Are you sure you don't want to check that the 10th character is whitespace, or that the 3 capital letters are a month abbreviation, or anything else?)

Comment: Yes I can translate and to be safe I would probably want to check to see if it is a month abbreviation.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

One way using a regular expression. This will find specifically the lines which you want to shorten by discarding the initial word while leaving the others unchanged.

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(re.sub(r'^\w{3}\d{6}\s+', '', line), end='')
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py final.txt >outfile
```

It yields:

```
MARVEL COMICS

AGE OF ULTRON HC        $75.00
ALL NEW X-MEN #16       $3.99
AVENGERS AI #3  $2.99
DAREDEVIL DARK NIGHTS #4
```

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: I've edited with your explanation but without removing the output. Thank you.